# How is it possible to cast an Android Activity to an interface?

Tags: java, android

In the Android documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html A Fragment implements an interface.

In the onAttach() callback, it seems to cast the current Activity to an interface. Conceptually, how is this possible and is the same type of cast standard practice in vanilla Java?

```
public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment {


// Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnArticleSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(Uri articleUri);


    OnArticleSelectedListener mListener;



    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnArticleSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some basic knowledge about the topic:

Think about an `interface` as a bundle of functions. If a `class` implements an `interface`, then it guarantees, that it has all the interfaces functions implemented.

In your case:

If you have an object and you don't need more than the functions of an interface, that your object implements, then you can treat (and cast) that object to that interface. This way you loose "information" about your object, because you won't be able to use its functions (except the interface functions), but sometimes its enough.

Answer (score 5):

Any object that is created from a class which implements some interface is also an instance of that interface.

Consider this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass mine = new MyClass();
        checkIsFoo(mine);
    }

    public static void checkIsFoo(MyClass mine) {
        System.out.print(mine+"");
        if (mine instanceof MyFoo)
            System.out.println(" is Foo!");
        else
            System.out.println(" is not Foo!");
    }
    public static interface MyFoo {
        //
    }
    public static class MyClass implements MyFoo {
        //
    }
}
```

In this case, the following is printed out: `Main$MyClass@52c8c6d9 is Foo!`. This indicates that the `MyClass` object is also an instance of `MyFoo`. Since they are shared instances, calling a cast to `(MyFoo) mine` would also be allowed.

This is, as @antlersoft said, part of vanilla Java (and can be seen [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/368060/java/java/Casting-Interfaces)).

Because, in this case, the `Activity` passed to `onAttach` should *always* be the object which is both the `Activity` and the `OnArticleSelectedListener`, casting it to `OnArticleSelectedListener` should always succeed.

Answer (score 3):

If the activity or one of its base classes is declared as implementing the interface, it is of course possible to cast it to the interface.

This is standard practice in vanilla Java.

If you aren't absolutely sure of the value onAttach is going to be called with, though, you should test with instanceof before you do the case.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Developer Guide doc, in Fragment section, in Creating event callbacks to the activity, written:

> the mListener member holds a **reference** to activity's implementation of OnArticleSelectedListener

What is mListener?

Answer is:

An Object in type of Listener(interface), where an activity object is located in it!
This activity object, in casting process, lost all field and method except same method with Listener interface. So, in the fragment, when we call mListener to do a method:

```
mListener.exampleMethod();
```

In simple word, "Hey mListener!" means, "Hey activity object, that lost all method except the ones that taken from interface", do that method!

*I'm sorry for bad English!*