# Why an activity object is casted to an interface in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, interface, casting

In the following link  https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/co/paulburke/android/itemtouchhelperdemo/MainFragment.java , Activity object is casted to an inner interface named OnListItemClickListener.

```
mItemClickListener.onListItemClick(position);
```

The whole source code of the MainFragment class is as the following :

```
public class MainFragment extends ListFragment {

    public interface OnListItemClickListener {
        void onListItemClick(int position);
    }

    private OnListItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public MainFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        mItemClickListener = (OnListItemClickListener) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        final String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_items);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        mItemClickListener.onListItemClick(position);
    }
}
```

Why does activity object casted to an interface?

There is similar question at stackoverflow [How is it possible to cast an Android Activity to an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204299/how-is-it-possible-to-cast-an-android-activity-to-an-interface)   but it is not satisfactory for me, it does not reply my questions.

Comment: Look into the Activity which adds `MainFragment `.

Comment: why don't you ask the one who wrote this code? only he knows that.

Comment: @MuratK. i updated my question. I wonder why activity is casted to interface..

Comment: Objected Oriented Design says  "Program to interface but not to implement" - this if you understand then you ll understand this design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @CommonsWare answer on why you have to cast it into `OnListItemClickListener`. The `onAttach` lifecycle method of the `Fragment` accepts any `Activity` - and an `Activity` does not have `MainFragment.OnListItemClickListener` implemented as default.

So the compiler does not know that, but you know that `MainActivity` has implemented it and with the cast you tell the compiler that `MainActivity implements MainFragment.OnListItemClickListener`.

Answer (score 1):

> This interface is not implemented in anywhere in the codes or i cannot see it

See [this line](https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo/blob/v1.1/app/src/main/java/co/paulburke/android/itemtouchhelperdemo/MainActivity.java#L27):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements MainFragment.OnListItemClickListener {
```

> but i cannot see any other implementation of this method..

See [these lines](https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo/blob/v1.1/app/src/main/java/co/paulburke/android/itemtouchhelperdemo/MainActivity.java#L44-L61):

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new RecyclerListFragment();
            break;

        case 1:
            fragment = new RecyclerGridFragment();
            break;
    }

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

> Why does activity object casted to an interface?

This is a typical implementation of the contract pattern. The fragment requires that its hosting activity implement a certain interface. That way, the fragment does not care what *specific* activity class is the one that hosts it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your activity `implements MainFragment.OnListItemClickListener`.

Besides, in your Activity, you will ned to implement the function `void onListItemClick(int position)`.